# 8086 assembly: MOV part of a string into a variable

Tags: assembly, x86, mov, addressing

Assuming I have a string of ascii characters such as "652+346*779=", and I want to move some characters FROM this variable TO another variable...

Buffer is the string (in this case "652+346*779=")
lengthofnum is the length of the number in question (in this case 346 has length 3)
A_ascii is the variable to which I'm trying to transport the string "346".

I have a loop that doesn't work at all, and I can't figure out what addressing mode I'm supposed to use.  emu8086 hates everything I've tried so far, and gives me errors regarding my syntax with the MOV instruction

```
mov cx,lengthofnum
dumploop1:
    mov bx, offset buffer
    ;dump the number from buffer into A_ascii
    mov A_ascii[cx],[bx]+cx
loop dumploop1:
```

I get the following error codes:

```
(672) wrong parameters: MOV  A_ascii[cx],[bx]+cx

(672) probably it's an undefined var: A_ascii[cx]
```

Comment: Might it have something to do with how I declared the variables?

     A_ascii dw 32 dup (?),0h

     B_ascii dw 32 dup (?),0h

     A dw 32 dup (?),0h

     B dw 32 dup (?),0h

     startofnum dw 00h

     lengthofnum dw 00h



With what you suggested, I get errors





(672) wrong parameters: MOV  dx, [bx]+cx


(672) probably no zero prefix for hex; or no 'h' suffix; or wrong addressing; or undefined var: [bx]+cx

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to (apparently) popular belief, you *can* do a direct mem->mem move on an x86, without (explicitly) moving to/from a register. Since you already have the length in CX, you're already started in the right direction:

```
mov si, offset A_ascii
mov di, offset B_ascii
rep movsb    ; automatically uses length from CX
```

Comment: I'd forgotten that `rep` and `movsb` are available on 8086. Good answer! :)

Comment: This answer is correct and is how you should do it.  I just want to add, though, that there is no `[bx]+cx` ever.  Operands are immediate, register, or memory only - you can't mix and match like that.  You can mix immediates/offsets/scales with registers as addresses in the form [(optional: any expression involving only immediates)+register(optional: multiply register by 2, 4, or 8)(optional: +register)].

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly move between two pointers. You need to move it into a register for temporary storage:

```
mov dx, [bx+cx]
mov [A_ascii+cx], dx
```

If you've got two blocks of memory that you want to move, the usual method is something like this:

```
  xor cx, cx                ; set counter = 0
  mov ax, addressOfSource   ; load base addresses
  mov bx, addressOfDest
move_loop:
  mov dx, [ax+cx]           ; load 2 bytes of data from source
  mov [bx+cx], dx           ; move data into dest
  add cx, 2                 ; increment counter
  cmp cx, dataLength        ; loop while counter < length
  jl move_loop
```

Comment: Yes, it seems your original code's syntax was a little off. I assumed you were using a strange compiler. I'll edit it to reflect that.